# How to re-write this batch.delete function to work for realtime database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a google cloud function, which currently works for firestore. I was able to convert the first variable into real-time database, but don't quite have the knowledge () to do the same for the rest of it.

**How do I perform this action in realtime database?**

```
  exports.cleanupUser = functions.auth.user().onDelete(async (user) => {
   const dbRef = admin.database().ref('stripe_customers');//admin.firestore().collection('stripe_customers');
   const customer = (await dbRef.doc(user.uid).get()).data();
   await stripe.customers.del(customer.customer_id);
   // Delete the customers payments & payment methods in firestore.
   const batch = admin.firestore().batch();
   const paymetsMethodsSnapshot = await dbRef
     .doc(user.uid)
     .collection('payment_methods')
     .get();
   paymetsMethodsSnapshot.forEach((snap) => batch.delete(snap.ref));
   const paymentsSnapshot = await dbRef
     .doc(user.uid)
     .collection('payments')
     .get();
   paymentsSnapshot.forEach((snap) => batch.delete(snap.ref));
 
   await batch.commit();
 
   await dbRef.doc(user.uid).delete();
   return;
 });
```

I attempting the following, but it did not appear to work:

```
 exports.cleanupUser = functions.auth.user().onDelete(async (user) => {
   const dbRef = admin.database().ref('stripe_customers');//admin.firestore().collection('stripe_customers');
   const customer = (await dbRef.child(user.uid).get()).data();
   await stripe.customers.del(customer.customer_id);
   // Delete the customers payments & payment methods in firestore.
   const batch = admin.database().batch();
   const paymetsMethodsSnapshot = await dbRef
    .child(user.uid).child('payment_methods').get();
   paymetsMethodsSnapshot.forEach((snap) => batch.delete(snap.ref));
   const paymentsSnapshot = await dbRef
    .child(user.uid).child('payments').get();
   paymentsSnapshot.forEach((snap) => batch.delete(snap.ref));
 
   await batch.commit();
 
   await dbRef.child(user.uid).delete();
   return;
 });
```

Comment: The equivalent of Firestore's batch write on Realtime Database is a multi-path update, where you pass the paths and values to write to the `update()` function. If you specify `null` as the value for a path, that path will be deleted. Converting the entire function is a bit beyond the scope of what Stack Overflow is for, but this should be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data structure of the Realtime Database is significantly simpler than Firestore which has both pros and cons.

For the Realtime Database, if you remove data at a location, all the data under that location is removed. This is different from Firestore, where you need to remove each document in each subcollection of a document you want to remove.

In short, this firestore code

```
const dbRef = admin.firestore().collection('stripe_customers');
const batch = admin.firestore().batch();
const paymetsMethodsSnapshot = await dbRef
  .doc(user.uid)
  .collection('payment_methods')
  .get();
paymetsMethodsSnapshot.forEach((snap) => batch.delete(snap.ref));
const paymentsSnapshot = await dbRef
  .doc(user.uid)
  .collection('payments')
  .get();
paymentsSnapshot.forEach((snap) => batch.delete(snap.ref));

await batch.commit();

await dbRef.doc(user.uid).delete();
```

gets flattened to just

```
const dbRef = admin.database().ref('stripe_customers');
await dbRef.child(user.uid).remove();
```

Which makes your function:

```
exports.cleanupUser = functions.auth.user()
  .onDelete(async (user) => {
    const dbRef = admin.database().ref('stripe_customers');

    // Firestore's .get() is the same as RTDB's .once('value')
    // Firestore's .data() is the same as RTDB's .val()
    const customer = (await dbRef.child(user.uid).once('value')).val();

    // user data already deleted? do nothing rather than throw errors.
    if (customer === null) {
      return;
    }

    await stripe.customers.del(customer.customer_id);

    await dbRef.child(user.uid).remove();
  });
```